# gnuplottex with 'subfolder' option: ps-file in subfolder not converted to pdf-file by epstopdf

Tags: pdftex, epstopdf

When I compile the following code (LaTeX -> pdf) without the option 'subfolder' at the 'gnuplottex'-package, it works fine.

The ps-file 'test-gnuplottex-fig1.ps', automatically created by gnuplottex, is converted to a pdf-file 'test-gnuplottex-fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf' by epstopdf, both files are in the same folder as the main tex-file.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage[miktex,subfolder]{gnuplottex}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{keyval}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{moreverb}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}%
\centering
\begin{gnuplot}[terminal=epslatex,terminaloptions=color,scale=1.0]
plot sin(x) notitle
\end{gnuplot}
\caption{}%
\label{}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

But adding the 'subfolder' option results in the error "Undefined control sequence" at the position in the tex-file where the pdf-file gets included because there's only a ps-file in the subfolder 'gnuplottex', but no pdf-file.

The error remains when I copy the pdf-file 'test-gnuplottex-fig1-eps-converted-to.pdf' to the 'gnuplottex'-subfolder.

How can I get the gnuplottex package to run with the subfolder option?

My system:

- MikTeX 2.9
- TeXnicCenter 2.0 Beta 2
- Windows 7
- 'gnuplottex'-package version 0.7 (2013/07/23)

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in gnuplottex. I've just uploaded a new version that should fix this.